# Clion and Maya debugging

Tags: clion, maya

I am working on a c++ Node for Maya on Clion.

I have a complicated array of arrays that I'd like to see the content.

So far I have inspected the array with MGlobal::displayInfo but it's too cumbersome.

I saw there's some tutorials to attach a process to Maya and inspect the locals, variables, etc.

Is this possible in Clion? I haven't found many resources about it. Thank you

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: If you know how to debug with Clion, the IDE does not matter as long as you use the microsoft visual c++ compilers and platform toolsets.